# pronunciation: airplane

Tags: pronunciation

> “crashed his remote control ***airplane***”  [[audio link]](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/401)
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

***Airplane*** sounds like in the audio /ˈerəpleɪn / instead of /ˈeəpleɪn/.
Is he really pronouncing the intrusive /r/, if yes, is it common?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In that recording, the speaker is pronouncing the word *aeroplane*. That is the word used in British English.

The word *airplane* is the word used in American English.

See [this link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/aeroplane?q=aeroplane) for *aeroplane*, where it has a recording of it being pronounced and also says (US **airplane**). [This link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/airplane?q=airplane) for *airplane* has recordings of American and English pronunciations and also says **US** for **aeroplane**.